# IIS serving locally, but not remotely

Tags: firewall, iis-6, port-forwarding

There is a router between the modem and the server. In the admin panel, I use single-port forward

```
Internal Port   External Port        IP
80              80              to   192.168.1.101 (Web Server)
```

Basically, I'm not on site, and there is a local IT person who is supposed to have this ready. I saw the port forward page, and it was configured as described above.

So my question is, the only other thing it could be is firewall software, or some other device on the network that their not telling me about, right?[alt text http://cognitivedesire.com/router.jpg](http://cognitivedesire.com/router.jpg)

**UPDATE:** I should mention, it is saying that "The server is taking too long to respond", as opposed to "Server cannot be found" if that changes the diagnosis.

Comment: Take a screenshot of your Port Forwarding page in the Linksys web interface (or give us the exact model number).  We can confirm if it's correct or not -- need to make sure that the source (src) port is NOT set to 80, it should be a range from 1-65535.

Comment: @gravyface - I attaached screen shot

Comment: You said the webserver was on 192.168.1.100, but that rule is for .101.  Also, you don't need "both", TCP will suffice.

Comment: @gravyface - yes, I did that accidentally. The rule is for 101, and ipconfig from that server show 192.168.1.101. - What about the switch? Could there be a firewall in there?

Comment: Did you try to telnet from another machine on the same network?

Comment: I doubt it's the switch, unless it's somehow a Layer 3 switch with ACLs turned on, but seeing as you have a Linksys Router, I doubt you dropped a couple grand on a L3 switch. :)

Comment: @gravyface - :) - I agree. I did the telnet, and was able to access the server from a machine inside the network.

Comment: @gravyface -  I should mention, it is saying that "The server is taking too long to respond", as opposed to "Server cannot be found" if that changes anything

Comment: Can you try restarting the Linksys?  Also, I'm wondering if your ISP is denying inbound port 80.  Some "home" connections deny port 25 and 80 so you can't host servers.

Comment: @gravyface - this is a place of business, and they have a business grade connection. Port 80 isn;'t blocked by the ISP because there was initially a camera system that could be access via port 80 from an external machine.

Comment: How are you testing this from the outside?  Are you on a different Internet connection? I don't know if Linksys routers do reflection (inside -> outside).

Comment: @gravyface - I'm testing this from outside the network. They have an internal IT guy who is stumped as well. I have been dialing in via webex to check configuration.

Comment: Have you ruled out a DNS issue?  From inside, go to http://www.whatismyip.org and try telneting from the outside to that IP on port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd test it from another machine on the same network (assuming that's your LAN) and see if it works.  If you can `telnet 192.168.1.100 80` (you'll get a new blinking cursor) then it's definitely a port forwarding/firewall issue and not a Windows firewall issue on the Web Server itself.

EDIT

Your port forwarding is for 192.168.1.101, not 192.168.1.100.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is a firewall issue or port forward is not setup correctly...

Check windows firewall is not running. Then verify the network topology and any devices that may be blocking port 80 to this machine.

What kind of router / firewalls are on site?

You can test by a telnet to port 80.

Comment: @Campo - They have a Linksys Router. I have personally disabled all the firewalls in the router, with no success. What about switches? I haven't worked with many that have firewalls. Could that be the issue..?

Comment: yikes, I'd put those firewall rules back in place.

Comment: I did, I was just testing momentarily...

Comment: Switches usually do not contain a firewall. If they do they are usually called firewalls...

If your server is 192.168.1.101 and not 192.168.1.100 then your settings seem ok.

You may try to open up the NAT on those ports, that could help.